# Change Order Confirmation Email For Specific Orders

Tags: email-templates, sales-order

I have two 'special' products that when ordered should send a custom email (in place of the standard order confirmation email).

An Observer is set up for the `sales_order_place_after` event but not sure how to change the email template for the order.

How do I change the email template for this particular order.

Comment: What type of customization do you want to do, is this just simple text changes or more complex design changes?

Comment: more complex, but open to just some text changes for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send different order conformation email depending on specific criteria you would either have to :

1. Rewrite `sendNewOrderEmail()` in Mage_Sales_Model_Order and add logic to check the template
2. Disable magento "order confirmation email" in system config, then create a custom module to send your email by coping logic from sendNewOrderEmail() using event/observer
3. For simple text changes, you could use template logic `{{if order.customer_group_id}}` or `{{depend order.customer_group_id}}` but they seem to only evaluate true/false condition, therefore for more advance logic you could include a block

> {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='sales/custom_logic.phtml' order=$order}}

In custom_logic.phtml

```
<?php
  $order = $this->getOrder()

  if($order->getCustomerGroupId() == 1){
     ///do
   ....
```

See [Magento Email Template If Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797394/magento-email-template-if-statements)

Comment: great answer! really appreciate the breakdown of options